# issue finding proper Google supported places type

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to implement GPS in my application, when user clicks the button in the app. it brings list of the nearest locations of the specified type "Religious Organizations" I did find a tutorial that does exactly what I want ,but when I surf Supported Places Types by Google places API I didn't find any hint for a matching type

So my questions are :

1-is there type but I didn't get please point me that type.

2-if there's no type is there a way to get a type to use it.

3- if none of the above how can I do.

please do share with me whatever "helpful" for my case so I can no more about this- as I'm new to Android-

thanks a lot

Comment: Please post the link to the tutorial you mentioned

Comment: here you go dude                                                        http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

Comment: @Homeliss what happened dude...could figure out the matter....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [this list](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)? You need to use it with [Place Searches](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches).

I didn't see a type for religious organizations, but I did see `place_of_worship`, `church`, `cemetary`, `mosque`, `hindu_temple` and `synagogue`

Comment: I mean list for the listview in Android. Yes I did also see those types but I don't think Organizations will fall under any of these,AGREE?  coz these in mostly for worship activities,and organizations not made for worship.So I wonder what type these organizations are match to when they appear in Google Places          hope you got me dude

Comment: The `Religious Organization` that you see on results when searching Google Maps comes from that company's Google Plus Page. The Places API cannot see this information.

Comment: okay so are you saying that there is no supported type of such places in Google places API.

Comment: I posted some possible solutions in my other answer. btw, why do you want to find religious organizations? Also, what exactly constitutes a religious organization in terms of your program?

Comment: I need these organization coz in my application I need to the user to be able to view it so use can contact any of them "location based" so I need to view the nearest one to the user so user can contact that organization

Comment: You can do that! I must've been tired yesterday, thinking on the completely wrong track, but have a look at my newest answer, I hope it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The Religious Organization that you see on results when searching Google Maps comes from that company's Google Plus Page. The Places API cannot see this information.

You have 2 options:

### 1: Search Google Plus

The [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) does not allow you to search for categories, but you could try using [this unnoficial API](https://github.com/mohamedmansour/google-plus-extension-jsapi#readme) instead. I am not familiar enough with either to help.

### 2: Use another list

Try find a list of organizations compiled by someone else. If you can't find one, you could compile your own. This could be time consuming though.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Religious_organizations
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_organizations

Comment: the 1st one seems a bit tedious-after a quick glance .the 2nd seems more simpler, but let's say I have a list of all the organizations in my country will it go this way 1- store the list in my DB in a table.            2-call the nearest one  based on the current user location and show it in a list view.                                                                 if that's the way how I should work it!!!!then could you please tell me how can I utilize the example I sent you to achieve that...what should I edit/add/delete                                                  thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

OK, my third and final answer!

You CAN perform a search for "Religious Organizations" near your users location!

In my previous answers I was looking to filter the search results to only Religious Organizations, which you can't do. But you CAN do a search for "Religious Organizations" in an area! I can't believe I missed that!

Heres a demo: Heres a demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/Homeliss/CZCLv/**

The code it uses:

```
function performSearch() {
    var request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.420538,153.028107),
        radius: '500',
        query: 'religious organization'
    };
    service.textSearch(request, textsearchcallback);

    return false;
}

function textsearchcallback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (p in results) {
            $('#placename').append(JSON.stringify(results[p].name) + '<br />');
            //For More Detail Use This:
            //$('#placename').append(JSON.stringify(results[p]) + '<br />');
        }
    } else {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
}
```

In my example I used a [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests), but a Nearby Search or Radar Search might suit your needs better, just read the documentation on how they differ.

eg: A Radar Search returns more results but each with less detail than a Nearby Search. Then if a user clicks a result you can perform a Place Details request to get more information

Comment: So if I'll perform the nearby search on what I should relay to get me the data?I read Yesterday that FourSquare API also have something similar to Google Places API,it uses venues.Instead but I wonder how it works and will it satisfy my app. req.ANY IDEA on that or generally is there any other alternative to Google Places API